# Changes to CSS don't affect site when online

Tags: css, public-website

I've used the new version Office 365 to design a public site which is just about done. I customized the CSS in various ways.

Things looks perfect when I'm working within Office 365. But when I make the site online and look at it that way, my CSS changes are missing.

What am I missing? What else do I need to do?

Tamar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to check in the css file. But if you change the master page with css files you have to publish a major version or apply the changes from the design manager in site settings.

Comment: Thanks. That was it, and that file is well-hidden to check in.